# There is no audio when video is played while ringer is silent on iPhone. using YouTube-Player-iOS-Helper

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, youtube-api, ytplayerview

I have used pod youtube-iso-player-helper to integrate YTPlayer within my native iOS application.

The issue, I am facing, is I am not able to hear any sound while the video is being played when the iPhone that has ringer silent & it works fine with earphone but does not work on iPhone speakers.

Note: I have not muted the iPhone volume, it's only ringer silent.

Comment: iPhone OS Version

Answer (score 1):

**Objective C:**

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
playerView.webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
```

**Swift**

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
do {
    try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    try audioSession.setActive(true)
} catch {

}

playerView.webView?.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false
```

Comment: The pod I m using does not setup any AVAudioSession, so this solution is not going to work for me. I am using YTPlayerView to play videos,

Comment: May be YTPlayer-helper does the "[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];" thing internally. but I don't find any thing where I can set this.

Comment: you can add this code in your view controller class anywhere (for example: viewdidLoad())

Comment: You must add YTPlayerView to a viewController right??,
add this code in viewDidLoad()

Comment: also disable mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction property for playerView's webview,....

Please refer above edited code

Answer (score 1):

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
            setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                  error: nil];